# Fill a shape (polyline (closed)) with a color and export it in dxf

Tags: python, colors, fill, dxf

I need the function in `ezdxf` to create a polyline and fill it out with colors:

```py
import ezdxf
dwg = ezdxf.new('AC1015') # hatch requires the DXF R2000 (AC1015) format or later
msp = dwg.modelspace() # adding entities to the model space
hatch = msp.add_hatch(color=2) # by default a solid fill hatch with fill color=7 (white/black) with hatch.edit_boundary() as boundary: # edit boundary path (context manager)
# every boundary path is always a 2D element
# vertex format for the polyline path is: (x, y[, bulge])
# there are no bulge values in this example
boundary.add_polyline_path([(0, 0), (10, 0), (10, 10), (0, 10)], is_closed=1)
dwg.saveas("solid_hatch_polyline_path.dxf")
```

This is from the documentation, but it is not working. If I passed it into `ipynb`, the error is:

```
AttributeError: 'Hatch' object has no attribute 'edit_boundary'
```

Answer (score 1):

This code follows the example included in `ezdxf`. Can you spot the subtle but important difference?

```
import ezdxf

doc = ezdxf.new("R2010")
msp = doc.modelspace()
hatch = msp.add_hatch(color=2)
hatch.paths.add_polyline_path(  # <<< LOOK HERE!!!!
     [(0, 0), (10, 0), (10, 10), (0, 10)], is_closed=True,
)
doc.saveas("hatch_solid_polyline.dxf")
```